# How to prevent \g subexpression from overwriting the grouped content in Ruby Regex

Tags: regex, ruby, regex-group

eg.

```rb
> /(?<ip>(?:\d+\.){3}\d+)\s*(?<mask>\g<ip>)/ =~ "1  abc  192.168.200.111 255.255.255.0"
> $~
=> #<MatchData "192.168.200.111 255.255.255.0" ip:"255.255.255.0" mask:"255.255.255.0">
```

according to the result above, `\g<ip>` captures "255.255.255.0", but also store them to `ip` group.

How to get the content of the first `ip` group: `192.168.200.111`.

Answer (score 3):

Reverse the subexpression call (I just found out by experimenting, not sure if it is robust)

```rb
>> /(?<ip>\g<mask>)\s*(?<mask>(?:\d+\.){3}\d+)/ =~ "1  abc  192.168.200.111 255.255.255.0"
=> 8
>> ip
=> "192.168.200.111"
>> mask
=> "255.255.255.0"
```

Comment: wow, it's great, your answer about subexpression order opens my world. thanks very much.

Comment: glad to help, it was a learning experience for me too :) also, see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) in case you haven't seen it yet